# Start fragment after pass data

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabactivity

I created a Tabbed Activity with 3 fragments. In fragmentA I download data from internet (with 3 AsyncTask) and i pass some data (static string and static arraylist) in fragmentB but I have a problem. 
FragmentB start when Tabbed Activity start. I want that FragmentB starts after FragmentA ends.

How can i do?

thanks

Sorry for my english

EDIT: Code FragmentA

```
public class P2 extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
View rootview;

static ArrayList<String> people10 = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> people12= new ArrayList<String>();
  static String nomedapassare;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_parla, container,false);


    Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
    String pkg = getActivity().getPackageName();
    Integer valore = intent.getIntExtra(pkg + ".myInt", -1);
    String parla= valore.toString();
    String url4 = url3 + parla



    if (isOnline()) {

        ApplicationSimpleAsyncTask3 asyncTask3 = new ApplicationSimpleAsyncTask3();
        asyncTask3.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR, url4);
         ApplicationSimpleAsyncTask2 asyncTask2 = new ApplicationSimpleAsyncTask2();
        asyncTask2.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, url2);
        ApplicationSimpleAsyncTask asyncTask = new ApplicationSimpleAsyncTask();
        asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, url);


    } else {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Attenzione!");
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setMessage("Connesione non più presente. Si prega di attivarla nuovamente!");
                  builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                getActivity().finish();
            }

        });
        builder.show();
    }

    return rootview;
}


public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity()
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (ni == null)
        return false;

    return ni.isConnected();
}







public class ApplicationSimpleAsyncTask extends
        AsyncTask<String, String, Document> {

    private final ProgressDialog dialog0 = new ProgressDialog(
            getActivity());

    protected void onPreExecute() { ...

    }

    protected Document doInBackground(String... valore) {
        url = valore[0];

        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(0).get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return doc;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(final Document doc) {

        try {
            if (this.dialog0.isShowing()) {
                this.dialog0.dismiss();
            }

           ...


           ArrayList<String> people = new ArrayList<String>();

            ArrayList<String> people2 = new ArrayList<String>();

            ...

            for (Element link : sitoVoto) {
                String linkHref = link.attr("href");
                people2.add(linkHref);

            }
            for (Element e : voti) {
                people.add("\n" + e.text() + "\n");
            }

            people10=people;
            people12=people2;





        } catch (Exception e) {...

        }

    }

}
```

}

I pass people10 e people12 in FragmentB but if asyntask is more fast I don't see nothing in FragmentB. While if asyntask is slow I see arraylist in FragmentB

EDIT2: FragmentB

```
public class V0 extends Fragment {
View rootview;
Document doc = null;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootview=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_voti_chiave,container,false);
    Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent(); // l'intent di questa activity
    String pkg = getActivity().getPackageName();
    Integer valore = intent.getIntExtra(pkg + ".myInt", -1);
    String parla = valore.toString();


    ListView listView = (ListView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    final TextView textview = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.textView20);



    if (isOnline()) {
        ApplicationSimpleAsyncTask asyncTask = new ApplicationSimpleAsyncTask();
        asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR, sito);


    } else {
        ApplicationSimpleAsyncTask asyncTask = new ApplicationSimpleAsyncTask();
        asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR, sito);
    }



    return rootview;
}

public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity()
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (ni == null)
        return false;

    return ni.isConnected();
}
public class ApplicationSimpleAsyncTask extends
        AsyncTask<String, String, Document> {

    private final ProgressDialog dialog0 = new ProgressDialog(
            getActivity());

    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    protected Document doInBackground(String... valore) {
                return doc;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(final Document doc) {

        try {


            ListView listView = (ListView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            final TextView textview = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.textView20);



            String text = "Ecco come ha votato " + P2.nomedapassare
                    + " nelle votazioni più importanti della legislatura";

            textview.setText(text);

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        getActivity(), R.layout.textview, P2.people10);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);



            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                                        long arg3) {
                    Intent newActivity = new Intent(getActivity(),
                            Esito.class);
                    String pkg = getActivity().getPackageName();
                    newActivity.putExtra(pkg + ".Nome", P2.people12.get(arg2));
                    startActivity(newActivity);

                }
            });




        } catch (Exception e) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setTitle("Attenzione!");
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setMessage("Connesione non più presente. Si prega di attivarla nuovamente!");
            builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    getActivity().finish();
                }

            });
            builder.show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}}
```

Here I can not erase AsyncTask otherwise the app crashes, but in this fragment I don't want to download data from internet

Comment: You should add your code snippets so we can understand your problem

Comment: @IshayPeled I added the code

Comment: You mean when you finish getting data in Fragment A then you want to automatically switch to fragment B? or you want your Fragment B unavailable while you are processing in Fragment A?

Comment: @VivekKumar I don't want to automatically switch to fragmentB. I want the fragmentB start execute the code when AsyncTask ends, because in fragmentB I put people10 in a ListView

Comment: Well you can try one thing... create another copy Fragment B without code use it as normal.. Make one with code and in onPostExecute() you can replace that fragment which has code.

Comment: @VivekKumar Maybe I did not understand, but in FragmentB I put people10 in a ListView inside onPostExecute()

Comment: The simplest solution (but not the best) is to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged` in the second fragment after you populate your ArrayList.

Comment: I tried but not work with  `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged`

Comment: but i did not try in `fragmentB.updateData`

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to do it is:

In Activity you create a method

```
void onDataReceived(String someData, ArrayList someMoreData)
{
    fragmentB.updateData(someData, someMoreData);
}
```

Preferably you move this method to an interface, let's call it `IDataReceiver`, and you make your activity implement this interface.

In `fragmentA` you need to get a reference to the interface, good place to do it is `onAttach()`:

```
IDataReceiver receiver = (IDataReceiver)getActivity();
```

And then when you get the data in AsyncTasks you just call the method on this interface and it will give the data to your second fragment, where you populate your views.

To get the reference to fragmentB in the activity you can use methods of `FragmentManager` class called `findFragmentById` or `findFragmentByTag`

Comment: Interesting but i don't think that solves my problem, because when fragmentB start I need immediately arraylist. I can not wait for the AsyncTask ends

Comment: You can create an empty arrayList and then swap it with the new one with data.

Comment: Good idea but how can I swap the two arraylist?

Comment: Something like `mArrayList = new ArrayList(passedArrayList);` if you are using it in a `ListView` or `RecyclerView` call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged` then.

Comment: I also posted fragmentB and now i try to swap arraylist

Comment: Nothing. When Asyntask in fragmentA is slow, I don't see nothing in the listview. 

in fragmentB I added:

`ArrayList mArrayList = new ArrayList(P2.people10);
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        getActivity(), R.layout.textview, mArrayList);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: You should do it in `fragmentB.updateData` and pass it the ArrayList you populated in the async task.

Answer (score 0):

1. First Create a one more Fragment B class, you can name it something else as for example "fragment_B_static". Remove all codes, leave only onCreateView() methods and which is actually for accessing layout.
2. In Fragment A, create a method something like "startFragmentB(List list)"

   ```
   private void startFragmentB(List<String> list){
     Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
           bundle.putStringArrayList("myList", new ArrayList<>(list));
              Fragment fragment = new FragmentB();
              fragment.setArguments(bundle);
              FragmentTransaction ft =  getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
             ft.replace(R.id.your_placeholder, fragment);
             ft.commit();
       }
   ```
3. Inside Fragment A . in onPostExecute() method, in the end you can call this method, `startFragmentB(people10);`

   4.Inside FragmentB.class, do this,

> ```
> @Override
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>
>     List<String> list = getArguments().getStringArrayList("myList");
>
> }
> ```

Comment: I put onCreate in Fragment_B_static but app crash in onCreate because of List<String>

 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.ArrayList android.os.Bundle.getStringArrayList(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
            at com.prova.prova3.V1.onCreate(V1.java:20)

Comment: I have a idea (not good). In fragmentA  i download a lot of string. Can i set a string as static and in fragmentB I controll with a while loop if string is empy or not? it's possible?